# Setting DisplayName on Register for Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication

> UserProfileChangeRequest(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, boolean, boolean)' is not public in 'com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

and

> Register.java:85: error: constructor UserProfileChangeRequest in class UserProfileChangeRequest cannot be applied to given types;
> UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest().Builder().setDisplayName(username).build();
> ^
> required: String,String,boolean,boolean
> found: no arguments
> reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I'm getting the above error from trying to set the display name on registering a user for firebase. How do i solve this?

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnSuccessListener(new O 
nSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest().Builder().setDisplayName(username).build();
                    user.updateProfile(profileUpdates);
                  startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomeActivity.class));
                  finish();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You done some mistakes:

YOUR CODE:
`UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest().Builder().setDisplayName(username).build();`

CORRECT CODE: 
`UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(username).build();`

You have to write `new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()` instead of `new UserProfileChangeRequest().Builder`
Remove "()" after `UserProfileChangeRequest()`

Thanks.